# Button is not changing color after other button is pressed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I want to make it where  my button is pressed it will show which button has been selected. However, I want it to go away after I make a new selection on a button. I have made a custom button (code below). When I click on the button, the button does change color immediately, but when I click on the second button, it does not change the background color back to the original color.

Button:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace InformationBookFinal.User_Control
{
public class FlatButton : Button
{
    public FlatButton()
    {
        BackColor = Color.DodgerBlue;
        ForeColor = Color.White;
        CurrentBackColor = BackColor;
    }

    private Color CurrentBackColor;

    private Color onHoverBackColor = Color.DarkOrchid;
    public Color OnHoverBackColor
    {
        get { return onHoverBackColor; }
        set { onHoverBackColor = value; Invalidate(); }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseEnter(e);
        CurrentBackColor = onHoverBackColor;
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        CurrentBackColor = BackColor;
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs mevent)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(mevent);
        CurrentBackColor = Color.RoyalBlue;
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
    {
        base.OnMouseUp(mevent);
        CurrentBackColor = BackColor;
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pevent);
        pevent.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(CurrentBackColor), 0, 0, Width, Height);
        TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter;
        TextRenderer.DrawText(pevent.Graphics, Text, Font, new Point(Width + 3, Height / 2), ForeColor, flags);
    }
  }
}
```

Button Action:

```
    private void flatButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        flatButton1.BackColor = Color.DodgerBlue;
        flatButton1.Hide();
        flatButton1.Show();

    }

    private void flatButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        flatButton1.BackColor = Color.Pink;
    }
```

Comment: Because CurrentBackColor never gets the update.

Comment: It should though shouldn't it because of the `CurrentBackColor = BackColor` piece?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the BackColor value, you aren't updating the CurrentBackColor value, which you are using in the Paint method.

So try overriding that property:

```
public override Color BackColor {
  get {
    return base.BackColor;
  }
  set {
    base.BackColor = value;
    CurrentBackColor = value;
    this.Invalidate();
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked nicely! Thank you!